# Convergence of LDA in MLLib spark

Tags: apache-spark, lda, apache-spark-mllib, topic-modeling

Is it true that there is no convergence step for LDA to stop when using spark MLlib. When I looked into the source code, I found the parameter updation will stop after the mentioned MaxIterations and not based on any Likelihood measure or something. Also is there any intuitive explanation of Likelihood and perplexity for topicmodels. How they can work as measures for a good fit of a topic model.